# param is missing or the value is empty: user (devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, devise

routes are correct, not sure what else is off?
upon "updating" page (*when it routes to update*) I get the error

> param is missing or the value is empty: user

This is my second custom view page for devise the other is working with similar code.

routes-

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'} as :user do  
end 
    root 'home#home' 

    get 'users/discovery_settings' => 'users#discovery_settings' 
patch 'users/discovery_settings/update' => 'users#update_discovery'
```

My user controller-

```
      def update_discovery
         @user = User.find(current_user.id)
         if @user.update(user_params2)
           # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
           sign_in @user, :bypass => true
           redirect_to root_path
         else
           render "edit"
         end   
    end



    def user_params2
    # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
    params.require(:user).permit(:discovery, :male, :female, :min_age, :max_age)   

end
```

Then my views form_for calls the method

```
  <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_discovery" }, html: {class: "form floating-label"})  do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out on my own and posted a blog about it, here was my answer:

Out of all the problems i've had customizing devise this one probably took the longest for me to figure out. A common error you will receive from doing this incorrectly is:

> param is missing or the value is empty: user

1st step is to create a controller that inherits the devise controller (essentially overriding it). This should go inside controllers/users and be called registration_controller.rb .

Insert the following code for a secondary customer edit view-

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

def NAMEOFVIEW
@user = current_user
if @user
render :NAMEOFVIEW
else
render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
end 
end
```

also you'll need to sanitize any custom parameters you make in your database

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :name, :user_age, :user_gender ) }
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :name, :user_age, :user_gender, :user_bio ) }

end
```

and finally allow updates without password (by default devise forces this)

```
protected

def update_resource(resource, params)
resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

Under routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}
as :user do

match 'users/NAMEOFVIEWHERE' => 'users/registrations#NAMEOFVIEWHERE', :via => [:get], :as => 'NAMEOFVIEWHERE'
```

then finally any changes in your view can be done using a form_for or a form_tag, form_for example below:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, class: " html classes here" }) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :Bio %><br />
<%= f.text_area :user_bio, autocomplete: "off", class: "optional html class here", rows: 3, cols: 20, name: "description", placeholder: "About" %>
</div>

<div class="optional button class here">
<button type="submit">Save</button> 
</div>
<% end %>
```

Now restart your rails server and cross your fingers!